# How to keep whitespace using Thymeleaf's th:each for inline dom?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf `th:each` loop, whitespace is removed (or can't be added).

Thymeleaf code:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline" th:each="for loop here"></a>
</div>
```

I expected:

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

but html rendered below.

```html
<div><a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 1</a><a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 2</a><a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 3</a><a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 4</a><a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline">Link 5</a></div>
```

How to add whitespace (in html file new line) using Thymeleaf `th:each`?

My Thymeleaf version is `3.0.12.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the links to be arranged horizontally with a single white space between them (as opposed to arranging them vertically using `display:block`) then you can use the Thymeleaf synthetic `<th:block>` element (documented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag)):

```html
<div>
    <th:block th:each="item : ${items}">
        <a href="#" th:text="${item}" style="text-decoration: underline;"></a>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

This will give you the same layout as you show in your question, when you run the first code snippet.

---

Update:

You can also use `<span>` instead of `<th:block>`, if you prefer:

```html
<div>
    <span th:each="item : ${items}">
        <a href="#" th:text="${item}" style="text-decoration: underline;"></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

This will give you the same end result (links arranged horizontally with a space between them), but the HTML generated to produce this layout will, of course, be slightly different.